# Customising image in the first row in a views

Tags: views

I would like to be print for the first row in different display style for the image field.
Thx all!

```
<div class="row first">
    <h3>Title1</h3>
    <img class="this is the first image with specific style of output"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h3>Title2</h3>
    <img class="standard style output"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h3>Title3</h3>
    <img class="standard style output"/>
</div>
<div class="row last">
    <h3>Title4</h3>
    <img class="standard style output"/>
</div>
```

I tried using the php field.
Something like:

```
<?php
  if ($view->row_index == 0) {
    print $row->field_foto_principale;
  } else {
    print "other";
  }
?>
```

But I can not render the image.

Comment: You can use the attachment feature of views. Which you can positioned above the block. So that attachment will be your first raw, and whatever you want you can do without affecting others.

Comment: is this for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Hi @No Sssweat. I use Drupal 7. I do not know attachment feature. Can you tell me about it?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to change CSS of first row the way you want without affecting other rows?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use hook

```
function HOOK_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'your_view_name' && $vars['view']->row_index == 1) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm using this code in a Custom PHP field:

```
<?php
    if ($view->row_index == 0) {
        $img_url = $data->field_field_foto_principale[0]['rendered']['#item'][uri];
        $style = $data->field_field_foto_principale_1[0]['rendered']['#image_style'];
    } else {
        $img_url = $data->field_field_foto_principale[0]['rendered']['#item'][uri];
        $style = $data->field_field_foto_principale[0]['rendered']['#image_style'];
    }
?>
<img src="<?php print image_style_url($style, $img_url) ?>" />
```